# MQJMS2000 Failed to close MQ queue in Mule

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, mule-studio, connector

I have a flow in Mule which puts order message in a WMQ queue. I am using JMS connector to connect to WMQ queue. This WMQ is a queue on the target system. The target system has a flow that pulls message from this queue. When there are burst of message hitting this WMQ queue, any one message cuts half. So if I check my logs, I can a see a warning "WARN org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector - Failed to close jms message producer: MQJMS2000: failed to close MQ queue". The target system is using WMQ version 6.0.2.3. I read the IBM support which says "JMS attempted to close a WebSphere MQ queue, but encountered an error. The queue may already be closed, or another thread may be performing an MQGET while close() is called". What can be done to resolve this?

Comment: IBM MQ  v6.0 was released June 24th 2005 and went out of support on September 30th 2012.  I would suggest you upgraded to a supported level of MQ and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: This problem was not arising for 5-7 years. When we migrated to Mule ESB after which we got this issue.

Comment: The version may or may not have anything to do with your issue but I would strongly suggest that you move to a supported version of the MQ client.  Newer MQ client versions can connect to older MQ queue managers.  You can download a java only install of [IBM MQ v8.0 Client](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24037500) or [IBM MQ v9.0 Client](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24042176) jar files for free.  Give it a try and see if it resolves the issue.